# How to remove words that contain a non-ascii letter in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a string like:

```
string='i like python in combination öööööüuto of vs code but there is äuto'
```

i want to remove all word that contain the non ascii words like "öööööüuto" and "äuto".

so finally i want to get:

```
string='i like python in combination of vs code 2 but there is'
```

How can i remove the no ascii words from a string in python 3.x? I want to keep the spaces between every word.

i can check the string with:

```
 string.isascii():
```

but this detects only the whole string as a non ascii string and gives me true or false.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with this: first a list comprehension of token, for token in splitted string, if the token isascii, and then a join over that list, with space as joiner.

```
string_ascii = ' '.join([ token for token in string.split() if token.isascii() ])
```